# Iterate on several vectors one after another?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`. I would like to know, is there any utility in range-v3 or std::ranges to iterate consecutively on the internal vectors?

I know there is `ranges::views::concat`, but apparently I have to list the ranges I want to concatenate.

Is there any way to do this?

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> vs;
auto v = ranges::views::concat(vs);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zKxzTevqc

Comment: Use `views::join`?